# Visual Studio 2015 new files not being added to source control automatically

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have just upgraded to VS2015 and I am experiencing an issue I have not seen before. Using an existing solution under source control, I am able to modify files and they get picked up as pending changes ready to check in to TFS.

However, I add a new file (Test.cs as an example in this screenshot), it is not picked up as a new file.

[image: Screenshot of new file vs modified file]

I am required to right-click it and click "Add files to Source Control"

[image: Add files to Source Control screenshot]

This has never been an issue before. I would like everything I add as a new file to be picked up as a pending change. How can I make this happen? I have not seen this before in previous Visual Studio versions.

I can confirm that this issue is the same on another machine. Also, the new file is not picked up in "Promote Candidate Changes" either.

If I then click "Add file to Source Control", I get this message.

[image: The selected file is ignored - add it anyway?]

"The selected file is ignored. Add it to source control anyway?"

My .tfignore file just has a directive to ignore packages, so I don't think this file is the problem.

How can I get my settings back on track?

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed that this only happens to the "Release" branch of my workspace. All other branches behave as expected. Furthermore, if I then take a branch "Release" and call it "Release1", the issue goes away entirely!

Do branches with the specific name "Release" take on any special functionality in TFS?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Folders called Release and their contents is automatically excluded from TFS (along with Debug and lots of file types). You can override this for particular folders by creating a .tfignore file, as detailed in the "Customize which files are ignored by version control" section of this [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server)

> Customize which files are ignored by version control
>
> By default certain types of files (for example, .dll files) are
>   ignored by version control. As a result:
>
> When you add ignored files to folders that are mapped in a local
>   workspace, they do not appear in the Pending Changes page in Team
>   Explorer.
>
> When you try to add ignored files using the Add to Source Control
>   dialog box (for example by dragging them into Source Control
>   Explorer), they automatically appear in the Excluded items tab.
>
> You can configure which kinds of files are ignored by placing text
>   file called .tfignore in the folder where you want rules to apply. The
>   effects of the .tfignore file are recursive. However, you can create
>   .tfignore files in sub-folders to override the effects of a .tfignore
>   file in a parent folder.
>
> .tfignore file rules
>
> The following rules apply to a .tfignore file:
>
> # begins a comment line
>
> The * and ? wildcards are supported.
>
> A filespec is recursive unless prefixed by the \ character.
>
> ! negates a filespec (files that match the pattern are not ignored)
>
> .tfignore file example
>
> Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
>  ProjA*.cpp
>
> Ignore .txt files in this folder
>   *.txt
>
> Ignore .xml files in this folder and all its sub-folders
>   *.xml
>
> Ignore all files in the Temp sub-folder
>  \Temp
>
> Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
>  !*.dll

Comment: @MartW This issue appeared recently. Looks like they changed something in this policy in last update of TFS.

Answer (score 12):

We were also experiencing this issue but in our case it was because we had folders that ended in ".Lib". Figured it out from this SO question: [Visual Studio 2015. Files not added to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932290/visual-studio-2015-files-not-added-to-tfs)

Answer (score 8):

We have the same issue because of a branch called 'Release'. But the issue is only at Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, everything is ok. So Visual Studio Update 3 must have been changed its behaviour. It would be useful to return to its old behaviour.

Comment: Yes we've alse experienced the same issue after upgrading to VS 2015 Update 3. No issues using previous updates of VS2015

Comment: I can confirm I've been experiencing the same problem with VS 2015 Update 3 on every branch name "Release" I've tested. The same branches run as expected on VS 2015 Update 2.

Answer (score 5):

Add a .tfignore file to the release folder containing the extensions you want it to not ignore:

```
!*.vb
```

I tried adding this to the .tfignore that existed in my solution folder and it didn't help. It only worked when I added one to the parent release folder.

```
..\Release
..\Release\.tfignore <-- this one
..\Release\SolutionA\
..\Release\SolutionA\.tfignore
```

[msdn thread on the subject](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/394cd8a3-da0b-40f3-bc59-6b8089251d2c/only-in-release-branch-the-selected-file-is-ignored-add-it-to-source-control-anyway?forum=tfsversioncontrol)