# Visual Studio 2015 TFS Newly added files not detected in changes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 with TFS hosted at visualstudio.com.
I added a new controller (xyzController) in WebAPI project. I was about to commit the solution but I found out that the new controller was not detected in changes but my edit on the existing controller (abcController) was detected.

I tried adding files to different folder and they are also not detected.
I also checked the icon beside the file, which is "lock" icon and the tooltip says that it was already "checked in". (which causes more confusion on my side)

My research on the internet (for a day) made me do these things:

- Refresh solution
- Unload/Reload project
- Add .tfignore file to negate changes on update 3 that causes some files to be ignored.
- Reset TFS cache [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) (causes to break my VS and made me repair it)

None of them fixed my problem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932290/visual-studio-2015-files-not-added-to-tfs) is somewhat the same question but the problem and solution is kinda different, but you can also check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several digging of different files in the solution. I found .gitignore file on the solution folder. Inside, the path "/Sol/Sol.WebAPI" was declared. Causing any files to be ignored in that path.

**Removing that path in .gitignore file causes the xyzController to be detected again as a change, newly added file. I just didn't thought VS also consider .gitignore files since I thought they had their own version of it which is the .tfignore file.**

Probably the reason why the edit on the existing file (abcController) was still detected is because the file (abcController) was already added and committed on the server before they added the .gitignore file causing it to actually "bypass the ignore parameter".