# Visual Studio 2017 Team Fundation Server(TFS) automatic add to source control not working

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I usually get this problem with my visual studio TFS.

When I add a new item (*.cs, *.js...), it does not add to the source control automatically. But the *.csproj file does include the file.

I am sure that I did not change any related settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by modifying the local config file *LocalItemExclusions.config*, because there is **.lib* in my solution's name, it will be excluded.

When I deleted this line `<Exclusion>*.lib</Exclusion>` in the config file,
it worked (or you can change the namestyle to avoid it).

Answer (score 0):

Double check if there are folders and branches called **Release** in your soucre control and their contents is automatically excluded from TFS (along with Debug and lots of file types). You can override this for particular folders by creating a .tfignore file.

More details about the solution please refer this similar question: [Visual Studio 2015 new files not being added to source control automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523861/visual-studio-2015-new-files-not-being-added-to-source-control-automatically)

If above is not working, check if you **source control binding** is correctly. *File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control*.

If not, bind the solution and project to your source control server (unbind first if it's already bound).