# How can I get git to automatically detect files added to Visual Studio 2017 projects?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a number .net core solutions in Visual studio 2017 and I've observed that on this particular machine (Windows 10 in Parallels on a MacBook pro) whenever I add new files to my project (or split a class into a separate file) git doesn't see it as an added file.

[image]

While preparing this question, I also observed that files that I manually add to these folders are also ignored.

I have to right click the file and select **Add ignored file to Source Control**. It's a real drag because I often only find out a file is missing after the build fails on VSTS. The source control indicator icons don't show up consistently, so it's difficult to know what's source controlled.

[image]

I also use Sourcetree, and neither this nor `git add -u` detects these files until I right click the file and add it from Visual studio solution manager.

[image]

I've searched for index.lock files, and tried to follow the other troubleshooting tips here: [Visual Studio: Git Team Explorer does not show any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053552/visual-studio-git-team-explorer-does-not-show-any-changes) but to no avail.

My git ignore file only contains:

```
**/.vs
**/obj
**/bin
```

**Edit**

I started looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523861/visual-studio-2015-new-files-not-being-added-to-source-control-automatically) and found that the problem is restricted to my project that ends with `.Lib`, files added to my other project folders are correctly detected! Is this a known issue?

- Am I missing a hidden ignore file somewhere?
- Is this a known issue?
- What else would cause git to ignore files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was the **.lib** folder name! I found a file called `\\Mac\Home\Documents\gitignore_global.txt`, removed the entry for `*.lib` and everything works as expected.

Yeah, I do feel silly, but the process of posting the question resulted in the solution.

Comment: Happened something similar to me. Someone added a folder to the .gitignore and it was excluding all new files on that folder.
I suppose Visual Studio has some Add Ignore feature that makes this easy.
Your case helped me find my problem.